# How do you send more than 2 forms to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I've gotten an assignment and it is:

> Make a website/page which processes forms. You shall have atleast 4 questions/forms and you need to process it in php. After that you should be able to tell the user what they got wrong and what they got right. You should also be able to write your name and it should appear on the php site somewhere.

So here I am with a site, I got 3 questions so far (I wanted to try before I went full scale). I use jQuery to hide and show the questions and I use radio inputs and a text input for the name. When I hit submit I've tried almost everything. Currently working with jQuery like this:

```
$(".knapp3").click(function() {
        $('#fraga1, #fraga2, #name, #fraga3').submit();
});
```

The php only processes the value inside #name which is my text input. My forms look like this:

```html
<div class="fraga1">
<h1>Hejsan?</h1><br>
<form id="fraga1" action="idk.php" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="tva" value="1">hej<br>
<input type="radio" name="tva" value="12">Hejsan<br>
<input type="radio" name="tva" value="13">Tjena<br>
</form>
</div>

<div class="fraga2">
<h1>Vad heter jag?</h1><br>
<form id="fraga2" action="idk.php" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="tva" value="2">qqq<br>
<input type="radio" name="tva" value="22">123<br>
<input type="radio" name="tva" value="23">xxx<br>
</form>
</div>

<div class="fraga3">
<h1>Vilken linje går jag?</h1>
<form id="fraga3" action="idk.php" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="tre" value="1">Teknik<br>
<input type="radio" name="tre" value="32">Samhälle<br>
</form>
</div>

<div class="namn">
<form id="name" action="idk.php" method="POST">
Skriv in namn: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
</form>
</div>
```

What is wrong? the php looks like this:

```
    <?php 
    $x = 0;
    if (isset($_POST["fraga1"])){ //if isset is nothing, therefore it doesnt run these statements.
        $fraga1 = $_POST["fraga1"];
        if($fraga1 == 1){
            $x+1;
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST["fraga2"])){
        $fraga2 = $_POST["fraga2"];
        if($fraga2 == 2){
            $x+1;
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST["fraga3"])){
        $fraga3 = $_POST["fraga3"];
        if($fraga3 == 3){
            $x+1;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo '<p>Nope</p>';
    }
    echo $x;
?> 

<?php 
echo $_POST["name"]; //Only this one is working.
echo $_POST["fraga1"]; //This one gives the error "undefined index"
?>
```

Comment: 4 questions per form. Have one form. You cannot submit 4 forms unless you have 4 different targets. Instead serialize the one form and ajax to the server. You can of course have your 4 forms and on submit of one of them have jQuery ajax all 4 but I think you will be better off with just the one form. Move the start form tag outside the first div and the end form tag after the last /div

Comment: you will never ever submit more then one form at the time

Comment: use one form or use multiple forms and a db/storage system to store the results of the forms to display them at the end

Comment: Also it is `$svar1 = $_POST["ett"]; $svar2 = $_POST["tva"];` - you want to change answer 1 to "ett" instead of "tva" - the ID of the form is not passed to PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. The solution is was like someone commented, to submit just 1 form and put all the data in there. To access it from php you just needed the name of the radio input.

Answer (score -2):

use the tag id="fraga1" /2/3/4 in your inputs and put them in one form, then use the following jquery-post to send it to php in onclick-event of submit button

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'idk.php',
        data: {fraga1:$('#fraga1').val(),fraga2:$('#fraga2').val(),fraga3:$('#fraga3').val(),fraga4:$('#fraga4').val()},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //do something...
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    });
```

you can use javascript jquery to $('.fraga2').show() and $('.fraga1').hide() the questions and at the end execute to post above in a button event. this is very basic programming, if you didn't have a idea how to do this i recommend reading 2 or 3 tutorials on basic php an js or go to a forum for dummis and not pros.

Comment: There are no fields called fraga. Also `$("#formID").serialize()` is a much simpler solution

Comment: I don't get it? How am i supposed to put 4 questions in 1 form? And make it so when I click the answear for 1 the next will appear.